# How can I alter the scaffolding code and also localize my application using Hebrew in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, crud, scaffolding

I've started to learn how to use the CakePHP framework for a part time job. And I decided to build one of my personal projects in this framework to get some practice on it.

1. I have some models I created using `Cake bake` command and I added the automated CRUD support (It adds to the controller `var $scaffold` for the all relevant actions.
   I want to edit these actions but I dont have a reference to the generated code. (As I said earlier, it adds the scaffolding member to the controller and that's it.)
   How can I edit these actions?
2. I want to build my application in Hebrew, I need to change all the generated error messages and status to Hebrew (Also the ones generated in the scaffolding). How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use "cake bake" again to bake your controller and views.
2. Read http://book.cakephp.org/view/162/Localizing-Your-Application

Comment: But when I cake bake it set the var $scaffold in the controller, but doesn't really generate any code.

The views are generated but not the controller, i get an empty controller with var $scaffold.

Comment: If you use Cake bake, you probably won't need to use scaffolding.  Just make sure to bake the views, which just generates the code that turning on scaffolding implicitly includes.  So if you bake and turn of scaffolding, you can edit the generated code.

Comment: You don't need to bake to localize. Just add the translation for the 'cake' domain into cake.po and all scaffold messages will be localized.